# How to create a GitHub local repository for a project in Visual Studio that has another project in the solution that already has a local repository

Tags: visual-studio, github

When this .net core 6.0 solution is opens in Visual Studio, the Git Changes window automatically points to the repository of the project that has a local repository. I want to create a new local repository for the other project in this solution that does not have a local repository currently.

Answer (score 0):

I've discovered that, in the bottom right hand corner of the VS UI you can either Select Repository or open that window and click the 3 dots and Create Git Repository. It looks like this solves the part of my problem I asked here.